# Very disturbing error message

Tags: c++

from third party codebase, I'm getting error:

**Error 140 error : a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function**

Function causing that error:

```
/** Static name of function to call */
    static FName GetAddComponentFunctionName()
    {
        static const FName AddComponentFunctionName(GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(AActor, AddComponent));
        return AddComponentFunctionName;
    }


// Returns FName(TEXT("FunctionName")), while statically verifying that the function exists in ClassName
// &((ClassName*)0)->FunctionName will generate 'error: cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function' on the Mac
#if PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    #define GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(ClassName, FunctionName) \
        ((void)sizeof(&((ClassName*)0)->FunctionName), FName(TEXT(#FunctionName)))
#else
    #define GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(ClassName, FunctionName) \
        FName(TEXT(#FunctionName))
#endif
```

And again, this code compiles with VS, but not with intel's icl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyObject->MyFunc`, as the error says, cannot be used for anything except an immediate function call. You can't even take its `sizeof`, even if some compilers allow that. I think what you mean is `sizeof(&ClassName::FunctionName)`. That's simpler, will actually compile, and doesn't invoke undefined behavior (dereferencing a null pointer is UB, even if you don't do anything with the dereferenced result).

Comment: *"dereferencing a null pointer is UB"* Not necessarily true, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232

Comment: @Sneftel, Hi, that code I've provided is just copy and paste. Thank you for your answer. Do I understand you correctly, in that you're suggesting to changing that macro expansion to sizeof(&ClassName::FunctionName)? Thank you

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando That should work, yes. Alternatively, you could just use the second implementation of `GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED` unconditionally. The first version is to provide error checking, not extra functionality.

Comment: @Sneftel, Hi, will try doing it and let you know how it went, and of course if it works I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Sneftel Hello again, indeed your answer is correct. It compiled. Unfortunately I'm getting now some linker errors, but that's different story. Thank you very much for your help.